# vue-croppa as component abnormal behavior, Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js

I am trying to use [`vue-croppa`](https://github.com/zhanziyang/vue-croppa) for image cropping and I installed it using `npm` as follows:

```
npm install --save vue-croppa
```

But when I use it as I normally would:

```
import Croppa from 'vue-croppa'
export default {
  components: {
    Croppa
  }
}
```

I get error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.

Instead I have to do this:

```
import Croppa from 'vue-croppa'
export default {
  components: {
    Croppa.component
  }
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/zhanziyang/vue-croppa#1-import-vue-croppa-into-your-vuejs-project
Look at the manual. It is not a component, but a plugin. You have to `Vue.use` it